# How to stop the user not to type space in the beginning of the text in UITextView iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to restrict the use of the spacebar in the beginning of the textfield in iOS. I tried to use the below logic but it is not allowing spaces anywhere between the words. Please help me in this case.

```
if self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()) != nil {
    return false
}
return true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do what you described, you can use the `textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)` method in `UITextViewDelegate`.

Example:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // as @nhgrif suggested, we can skip the string manipulations if 
    // the beginning of the textView.text is not touched.
    guard range.location == 0 else {
        return true
    }

    let newString = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text) as NSString
    return newString.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).location != 0
}
```

First, we construct the new string that will be shown in the `textView`.

And then we check if it start with a whitespace, tab or newline character.

If so, we return `false` so the the `textView` won't place the new text in.

Otherwise, put the new text into the `textView`.

Note: We need to check the whole string instead of checking the `replacementText` to deal with copy-paste actions.

---

Another possible way is *not* restricting the text the user typed, but trimming the result text when you need to use the value.

```
let myText = textView.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

---

Edit: add a `guard` clause to make the method more performant based on @nhgrif's comment.

Comment: We can probably optimize this slightly by adding this line at the top `guard range.location == 0 else { return true }`.  If `range.location` is `0`, we will somehow have a new character at the very front.  If it's not, we can skip the relatively expensive string manipulation checks.

Comment: Thank you @nhgrif !  This is really cool, I've edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

*For TextField*

**Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard range.location == 0 else {
        return true
    }

    let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    return newString.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).location != 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this in textView delegate:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    guard range.location == 0 else {
        return true
    }
    let newString = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text) as NSString
    return newString.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).location != 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1**

**Just simple with Single line of code you can stop whitespace**

**For All UITextView**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
}
```

**For Single  UITextView**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if textView == textViewArea
    {
        textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {        
        if (range.location == 0 && string == " ") {
            return false
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here improvement in Answer You can disable blankSpaces until your First Character Enter

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
    let range = text.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet)
    if let _ = range {
        let txt = textView.text ?? ""
        if txt.isBlankByTrimming || txt.isEmpty {
            return false
        }else {
            return true
        }
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

After this  before saving your final string you Can trim Spaces and newline from End Of the string .

```
Example : "MyName Surname             "   

extension String {
       var isBlankByTrimming: Bool {
                 let trimmed = self.trimmingCharacters(in: 
                     CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
                       return trimmed.isEmpty
                    } 
        func trimWhitespacesAndNewlines() -> String{
                  return self.trimmingCharacters(in: 
                                    CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            }}
```

for use ::

```
let yourString = "MyName Surname          " 
let finalString = yourString.trimWhitespacesAndNewlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//User never input space in text field(swift 5)...
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:   NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if string == " "   {
    // If consecutive spaces entered by user
     return false
    }
 }
```